# Using a apple tv box as a second monitor to your osx machine

Tags: macos, display, appletv

I've heard that you can use as ipad as a second monitor to you macbook by using software like iDisplay.

Is it possible to use apple TV in a similar capacity?

If so then:
a. Which software do I use?
b. What types of appleTvs will allow that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible, yes, but apparently nobody has written a suitable driver yet.

Comment: I would say you might specify which Apple TV you have and restrict software to just that model or perhaps edit that out and ask a follow on question if you find a product that works, but doesn't work for your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is due in the fall with [the next OS X version](http://www.apple.com/osx/preview/#multiple-displays).  You'll have to wait a few more months.

Comment: Where did you get that piece of information?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something as easily accomplished since for iOS to act as a second display, an App provides that functionality. Since you cannot add apps easily to an Apple TV, you are constrained to mirroring the display, not extending it from OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the current moment. What you have right now is just mirroring the display.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible today on iOS 6 and OS X 10.8 using air parrot software:

http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/